# Multilevel list formatting problems, promotion/demotion remove numbering

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2016

When I attempt to modify a multilevel list, by promoting or demoting sections, the numbering formatting goes away for the section and any subsections underneath it.  I have to go up and click on numbering again for each section and subsection.

Comment: Maybe you can consider to use Outline view to change the heading format and levels for your document. Check this article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-document-outline-in-outline-view-cfdd43c9-021f-4d5d-a678-34a182f4433c

Comment: The same behavior is exhibited when the edits are made with the outline view controls.  I also see no place to indicate that "heading levels should have the numbering applied"

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a multiline list style that does this.  The iconography doesn't quite make sense but I'll just post a picture[of the options in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHshh.png).
The one that is X'd out looks like it will give you numbering, until you change the text to be a heading, then the numbering goes away.  Once I saw that, I looked closer at the styles and saw the one with the checkmark, which does what I want.